# How to change FlxG width and height, ResizeGame doesn't work

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

how do i change FlxG width and height in runtime as resizeGame doesn't do anything

i have the project by default set to 1600 x 900 and i have a state for settings where i can change the resolution and have managed to make it so that i can change what the width and height will be on startup however i want to be able to resize it during runtime so it will be higher/lower res.

the problem is since FlxG width and height aren't modifiable directly so according to the API resizeGame is the only option but it doesn't do anything, even after calling it and tracing FlxG width and height there is no difference nor is there any visual difference asside from the game being offset to the very top left corner of the window and messing up detecting where the mouse is until i resize the window in some way where it goes back to normal

i'm compiling to c++ (windows)

edit: it has been a couple of months and i have started mostly rewriting the program and yet this issue is still a thing on a fresh start and i am in serious need of an answer

edit 2: I've done some deep diving into the code itself (i checked in FlxGame, FlxG and BaseScaleMode) to figure out what exactly the function does and i realise that it seems kinda nonsensical, firstly when creating the FlxGame object it sets initialWidth and initialHeight to the values when initialising which i can't find what they are used for nor can i figure out how they can be used (the API lists them says nothing about them) aside from being used in BaseScaleMode.onMeasure to set FlxG.width and FlxG.height to the values provided in initialisation, why??? its supposed to set them to the values provided in the resizeGame function not reset it to what it was to begin with which is what it is currently doing and that contradicts the API documentation

edit 3: i have since re-installed the entirety of haxeflxiel from the start since the newest flixel version does not support haxe 4.1.5 which i was using before, i did this to see if any of my multiple issues would be fixed and they are not, this specific one is still an issue with no differences and still no closer to any answer of any sort

edit 4: i went into the files in HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\flixel\5,3,1\flixel and changed the code in a few places then compiled to see what happens, i have realised that gameSize in BaseScaleMode does absolutely nothing, i commented it out and there was literally no difference to the game, why it it there?
i also found that resizeGame is used in FlxGame in onResize(_) which makes me realise resizeGame does absolutely nothing to change FlxG.width and FlxG.height unlike what it is stated to do in the API as it seems more like a "fit the game into the window" function than a "change the game's resolution" function

all of my searching leads me to believe that the api is incorrect about what resizeGame does and that there is seemingly currently no way to change FlxG.width and FlxG.height

does anyone have a proven way of changing the game size or am i mising something somehow?